# When a woman says ''no problem'' to thank you, is she being disrespectful?

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms, possessives, doubled-words

I am curious to read your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: Huh? Why would a woman saying something be any more or less disrespectful than a man saying the same thing? Unless you come from a particularly sexist society, in which case this has nothing to do with the language and everything to do with the social issues of that society.

Comment: SE is not a forum. It is a question and answer site for real problems you are having. "I'm curious to hear your answer" is pretty indicative of a poorly written/considered question.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase "no problem" is not at all disrespectful.  The general meaning is "[helping you was] no problem".  Think of it as the person reassuring you that it was not an inconvenience to help you.

The phrase can be considered casual, but there are very few situations where it would be considered out of place or incorrect.